# Webservice TFS Online Preview

Tags: c#, web-services, tfs, azure-devops

i want to access my team foundation server (online preview) webservice by c# code. My problem is to find the right address to connect the webservice ("http://XXX.tfspreview.com" is not the right address). 
Does anybody know this address or has some information?

Search on the microsoft homepage got no results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thread on this very subject

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/a56269d8-7840-4d48-b77a-5aaf1976a2a6/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this namespaces

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
```

Sample (Service Locator TfsTeamProjectCollection )

```
  TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsURI"));
  var service = (YourTypeOfService)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(YourTypeOfService));
```